# Magento2 - How to display custom attributes on Product Details page near product name

Tags: magento2

How to display custom attributes on Product Details page near product name?.

Here **Manufacturer Name** and **Manufacturer Number** is custom attributes. which value i want to show on Product Details page near product name.

[image]

Using this code **view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.demo" template="Custom_ProductAttribute::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDemoLink</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer_name</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">manufacturer_name</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Manufacturer Name</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer_name"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml**

```
<?php

 $manufacturerName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer_name');
echo $manufacturerName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to display custom attribute on PDP

**Manufacturer Name :**

```
$manufacturerName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer_name'); 
echo $manufacturerName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

**Manufacturer No :**

```
$manufacturerNo = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer_no'); 
echo $manufacturerNo->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: I edit the question can you please check is it right?

Comment: You have to add in .phtml not .xml

Comment: here i added view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

Comment: Can you guide me steps please.

Comment: Please share SS where you have to display?

Comment: Please check SS, Now availble in question

Comment: Need to call custom phtml and using product object can display custom attributes

Comment: Yes i understand but can you please share me steps please